# How can I uninstall previous version windows application use install Shield script?

Tags: windows, installshield, installscript

I have an InstallShield project, and try to build setup.exe file, now I have an old version application installed in my PC, and I need to uninstall this old version application, then install the new version of this application, I use below script:

```
function UninstallOld()
begin                             
  LaunchAppAndWait("msiexec.exe", "/x {product GUID} /qn", LAAW_OPTION_WAIT);
  UninstallApplication("{product GUID}", " /x /s", LAAW_OPTION_WAIT);
end;
```

But it doesn't work, could anyone shed me some lights on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is an MSI project you can update the Upgrade table and uninstall older versions as a "major upgrade". If this is legacy Installscript (which shouldn't really be used for most purposes), please let us know. Perhaps it is an Installscript MSI instead? The special MSI flavor with Installshield's own GUI?

Comment: As Stein mentioned you should be performing major upgrades using the MSI Upgrade table. One big issue with launching from install script is that only one MSI can be running at a time within the InstallExecuteSequence.

Comment: Yes, I should have pointed that out. Thanks for adding. Let me add a link of a slightly different variety too: [Upgrades Overview](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/UpgradingYourApplication.htm).